# Where is the Views option that allows me to arrange/sort files in Files (Nautilus)?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, directory

I am on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I am trying to set the way files are arranged/sorted in a folder. Everywhere I search for how to arrange files in folders, gives me the same answer as [the official GNOME help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/nautilus-views.html.en): to find an option inside *Preferences* labeled *Views*:

> [image: screenshot from GNOME help describing Views preferences in Nautilus]

However, I have no such thing as a *Views* option or tab, in my folder options. I can find no way to set the arrangement of files in the icon view. List view, as normal, can be sorted by clicking the list headings, but that sorting does not apply to the icon view.

Here are the options I have when clicking the burger menu of Nautilus:

> [image: options in burger menu of Nautilus]

And here are the options inside *Preferences*:

> [image: options inside Preferences]

Where can I find the mentioned *Views* option so I can change the sorting of files in Icon view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found how to actually do it. As I said there is no *Views* option anywhere, yet all help files I found seemed to point to one. Here's a picture of where the file arrangement options actually are:

[image: Option to arrange files in Nautilus]

Surely I'm not the only one out there with a little down arrow button, instead of a *Views* option.